# How to prepare browser or system settings for asp.net testing environment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, testing, web, automated-tests

There has a scenario about testing the dark/light mode.
I found a [blog](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/12/13/test-your-web-app-in-dark-mode/) that it can set the browser or system settings before running test:

```
args.push('--force-dark-mode=true')
```

I curious if ASP.Net can do this within the testing framework or others nuget packages like anglesharp?

Comment: How to prepare system settings for asp.net testing environment ?do you mean appsettings and add ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to web.config ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

adding this ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to web.config

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyCustomers.Services.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
    </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

and then change ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to be

- Development
- Staging
- Production

Comment: Sorry, I mean "mock" the system theme setting to dark or light before running testing. Because the page has js that do some logic depend on this setting.